# Test iOS app without xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm sorry if this may seem a stupid question, but so far I have only developed Android apps and have no knowledge of iOS development.

I'm working for a company that wants me to test their Android and iOS app which are developed by an external company. The external company provides us test versions for both platforms via HockeyApp.

My question is now, is there a way to run the iOS test versions I receive on a Macbook with the Xcode simulator or do I need to ask the external company for the Xcode project in order to test the app with the Xcode simulator? We mainly want to use the simulator to test the app on different screen sizes/resolutions.

Comment: HockeyApp is build only support the real device. If you want to test in simulator you need the project code.

Comment: I was afraid that this is the case, thank you very much for the quick answer!

Comment: Or you can drag and drop the .app into the simulator, but the project must be builded for simulators.

Comment: You don't need the project code, just the .ipa file that was compiled for a simulator, then go XCode -> Windows -> Device & Simulators then drag and drop the .ipa file under the installed apps section.

Comment: Nope, the .ipa file includes a binary for the ARM architecture  (iOS device) not x86 (simulators).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request the .app file of the application, builded for simulator.

Then if you have a Xcode version >= 8.2 you can just drag and drop the file into the simulator and test it.

Comment: That worked very nice, thank you very much for the tipp! :)